# Add AppBarCommand to AppBar in WinJS

Tags: winjs, windows-10, appbar

I need to add an `AppBarCommand` to an `AppBar` programmatically.  This used to work on Windows 8.1, but it's not working on Windows 10.  I receive no errors, but when I execute the below code, my application bar is empty.  Does anyone know if adding `AppBarCommand`s to the `AppBar` dynamically from WinJS is possible anymore?  If so, how can it be done?  Thanks.

Although my problem was occurring within a larger existing application, I reproduced the problem from the "Blank" WinJS template.

default.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                var appBarDiv = document.createElement("div");
                document.body.appendChild(appBarDiv);
                var appBar = new WinJS.UI.AppBar(appBarDiv, {});
                var command = new WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand(null, { id: "commandID", type:"button", label: "Label", section: "secondary" });
                appBar.commands = [command];
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }
    };
    app.start();
})();
```

default.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App1</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="WinJS/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="WinJS/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="WinJS/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- App1 references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="win-type-body">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @TheTanic, no.  I had to give up on programmatic additions and removals.  Hopefully they'll fix it someday.

Comment: Did you try to use the data property instead of commands? [From the Appbar] This works for me

Comment: @TheTanic, I don't know enough about that.  If you can post a working answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: so did you try it?

Comment: @TheTanic, yes.  But it didn't work.  Thanks though.

Comment: What didnt? Work? I use in my own winjs Applications and I dont have Problems

Comment: @TheTanic, the result was the same as my original problem.  I don't get any errors, but nothing happens.

Comment: So i made a complete example. Take a look. It worked for me

Comment: Did the new example work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create **all** buttons at the start but then make them *hidden* or *visible* dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I realized this, with using the `data` property of the `WinJS.UI.AppBar`:

First you need a variable for the Binding list:

```
var commandList;
```

Create the AppBar:

```
 function createBar() {
    var appBarDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var appBar = new WinJS.UI.AppBar(appBarDiv, {});
    commandList = new WinJS.Binding.List([]);
    appBar.data = commandList;
    document.body.appendChild(appBarDiv);
}
```

Function to Create Commands:

```
function createCommand(id, label, tooltip, icon, section) {       
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var command = new WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand(btn, {
        id: id,
        label: label,
        tooltip: tooltip,
        icon: icon,
        section: section,
        type: "button"
    });
    return command;
}
```

Function to Add Commands to the AppBar:

```
function addCommand(id, label, tooltip, icon, section) {
    commandList.push(createCommand(id, label, tooltip, icon, section));
}
```

This worked for me. 
Of course you can allready add Commands in the `creatBar()` function.

**EDIT:**
Here a complete example, which creates 10 commands and add them to an allready created AppBar:

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TestApp</title>

    <link href="lib/winjs-4.0.1/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="lib/winjs-4.0.1/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/winjs-4.0.1/js/ui.js"></script>

    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="win-type-body">
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```js
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509

(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
    var isFirstActivation = true;
    var commandList;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {

        if (isFirstActivation) {

            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }

        isFirstActivation = false;
    };

    WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {

        createBar();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            addCommand("test" + i, "test" + i, "test" + i, "street", "primary");
        }
    });

    function createBar() {
        var appBarDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var appBar = new WinJS.UI.AppBar(appBarDiv, {});
        commandList = new WinJS.Binding.List([]);
        appBar.data = commandList;
        document.body.appendChild(appBarDiv);
    }

    function createCommand(id, label, tooltip, icon, section) {
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        var command = new WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand(btn, {
            id: id,
            label: label,
            tooltip: tooltip,
            icon: icon,
            section: section,
            type: "button"
        });
        return command;
    }

    function addCommand(id, label, tooltip, icon, section) {
        commandList.push(createCommand(id, label, tooltip, icon, section));
    }


    app.start();

})();
```